# Oracle SQL - Найти максимальные значения для групп строк в запросе

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Есть две таблицы: в одной хранится имя компании и номер заказа. Во второй - номер заказа, количество единиц одного товара в заказе, цена за единицу и скидка. Компании делали более одного заказа. Нужно вывести имя компании, номер заказа этой компании с максимальной стоимостью и саму стоимость заказа. При этом в заказе может быть несколько товаров, поэтому сначала нужно просумировать стоимость всех товаров в заказе (как количество_единиц*стоимость_за_единицу*(1-скидка)), а потом уже находить максимальный заказ. Вся сложность состоит в том, что (это тестовое задания) в запросе может присутствовать только одно слово select. Решаю так:

```
select distinct cust.companyname, ord.orderId, sum((details.unitPrice * details.quantity) * (1 - details.discount)) over (partition by ord.orderId)
from customers cust, orders ord, orderdetails details
where cust.customerId = ord.customerId 
and ord.orderId = details.orderId
order by cust.companyname, ord.orderId
```

В результате получаю имя компании, все ее заказы и их цены. Теперь нужно выбрать для каждой компании максимальный заказ и тут у меня трудности. Как я понимаю, я не могу использовать аналитические функции одна в одной, например, max(sum() over()) over() (т.к. нигде не нашел упоминания о подобной возможности), но при этом обернуть полученный результат в еще один select тоже нельзя. Можете подсказать как можно выйти из подобной проблемы?

Таблицы в базе:

[image: Таблицы в базе:]

Предполагаемый ожидаемый результат:

CompanyName OrderId Price

Alfreds Futterkiste                 11011   933.5

Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  10926   514.4

Antonio Moreno Taqueria 10535   1940.85

Around the Horn 10953   4441.25

B's Beverages   11023   1500

[image: Ожидаемый результат:]

Текущий результат:

CompanyName OrderId Price

Alfreds Futterkiste 10643   814.5

Alfreds Futterkiste 10692   878

Alfreds Futterkiste 10702   330

Alfreds Futterkiste 10835   845.8

Alfreds Futterkiste 10952   471.2

Alfreds Futterkiste 11011   933.5

Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  10308   88.8

Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  10625   479.75

Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  10759   320

Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  10926   514.4

Antonio Moreno Taqueria 10365   403.2

Antonio Moreno Taqueria 10507   749.0625

Antonio Moreno Taqueria 10535   1940.85

Antonio Moreno Taqueria 10573   2082

Antonio Moreno Taqueria 10677   813.365

Antonio Moreno Taqueria 10682   375.5

Antonio Moreno Taqueria 10856   660

Around the Horn 10355   480

Around the Horn 10383   899

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Извиняюсь за задержку. Вот возможная схема:

```
create table customers(
  companyname varchar2(100),
  customerId  varchar2(100)
);

create table orders(
  customerId varchar2(100),
  orderId number
);

create table orderdetails(
  orderId number,
  unitPrice number,
  quantity number, 
  discount number
);

insert into customers values('Alfreds Futterkiste','ALFKI');
insert into customers values('Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados','ANATR');

insert into orders values('ALFKI',10702);
insert into orders values('ALFKI',10952);
insert into orders values('ALFKI',10835);
insert into orders values('ALFKI',11011);
insert into orders values('ALFKI',10643);
insert into orders values('ALFKI',10692);
insert into orders values('ANATR',10759);
insert into orders values('ANATR',10926);
insert into orders values('ANATR',10625);
insert into orders values('ANATR',10308);

insert into orderdetails values(10308,28.8,1,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10308,12,5,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10625,23.25,3,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10625,14,5,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10625,34,10,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10643,45.6,15,.25);
insert into orderdetails values(10643,18,21,.25);
insert into orderdetails values(10643,12,2,.25);
insert into orderdetails values(10692,43.9,20,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10702,10,6,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10702,18,15,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10759,32,10,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10835,55,15,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10835,13,2,.2);
insert into orderdetails values(10926,21,2,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10926,6,10,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10926,9.2,7,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10926,34.8,10,0);
insert into orderdetails values(10952,25,16,.05);
insert into orderdetails values(10952,45.6,2,0);
insert into orderdetails values(11011,13.25,40,.05);
insert into orderdetails values(11011,21.5,20,0);
```

И полное задание:

> Для каждой делавшей заказы компании из таблицы CUSTOMERS вывести имя
>   заказчика (companyname), номер заказа (orderid) из таблицы ORDERS,
>   который имел наибольшую стоимость, и саму стоимость этого заказа с
>   учетом скидки (из таблицы ORDERDETAILS). Примечание: предполагается,
>   что запрос будет содержать только одно слово SELECT

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста минимальный пример заполнения таблиц и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: думаете для тестирования все должны дружно переписывать текст с рисунков себе? выложите пример исходных данных в виде текста (а лучше insert-запросов)

Comment: по сабжу, вам не две оконных (аналитических) функции  наверное надо использовать, а суммирование с окном, и масимум с группировкой по компании. вопрос в том, что делать с номером заказа, надо знать поведение оракла, можно ли просто выбрать номер, и будет ли он соответствовать максимальной сумме

Comment: @Александр выкладывайте пожалуйста текстом, а не картинками. И покажите еще ожидаемый результат, а не только то, что у вас вышло

Comment: Проблема в том, что какой точно результат должен быть я не узнаю, пока не сделаю запрос. Пока я хочу понять как я могу выбрать заказ с максимальной ценой для каждой компании.

Comment: и запросы на джойны с условиями перепишите все

Comment: в оракле для таких целей есть отличная конструкция model. правда она тяжеловата для освоения. http://apps-oracle.ru/model-2/

Comment: @Okdel Вы встречали хоть один случай, когда model был бы действительно нужен. я его посмотрел немного но так и не смог пока придумать ни одного реального применения

Comment: @Mike сталкивался с его использованием при подведении сложных промежуточных итогов. Сам бы зашел с другого края. Но в данном случае как один из вариантов решения он мог бы быть.

Comment: Добавил пример базы и задание, как оно звучит полностью. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аналитические (оконные) функции в запросе применяются после группировки и применения агрегирующих функций к группе. А после всего этого применяется distinct. поэтому сначала группируем данные до заказов, получая суммы и оборачиваем все поля аналитическими функциями так, что бы во всех строках были данные по максимальной цене. И добавляем distinct.

Примерно так (вы не дали нормальных таблиц для теста, так что пример пришлось упростить до минимума (что и вам стоило сделать изначально)):

```
select distinct o.company,
       first_value(o.ord) over(partition by company order by sum(price) desc) ord,
       max(sum(price)) over(partition by company) price
  from t_orders o, t_detail d
 where d.ord=o.ord
 group by o.company,o.ord
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab1d1f/1)